# Get data from multiple table using single query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

1. Pricing (id, status)
2. Billing (id, status)
3. Compliance  (id, status)

id & status are the columns of the table. there is no any connection between these tables(no primary key-foreign key relationship), I mean they all are independent tables.

I have only 1 record in every tables, so there will be only 1 id & only 1 status in the table. So I wanted to get the status from every table along with the table names in **only single query**

My expected output:

```
table Name        status

Pricing            1
Billing            2
Compliance         3
```

**Note: I am looking for only single query solution for this.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using `UNION` ?

Comment: Actually UNION is also a combination or multiple queries, But i am looking for any other option

Comment: Are you OK with `JOIN` ?

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this....

```
    SELECT
        STATUS,
        'Pricing' as TableName
    FROM
        Pricing

    UNION

    SELECT
        STATUS,
        'Billing' as TableName
    FROM
        Billing

    UNION

    SELECT
        STATUS,
        'Compliance' as TableName
    FROM
        Compliance
```

or You can use subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.You just have to create a table number with the column 'n' and insert 1 to 10 values in it. Then below query will work as per your expectation.

```
 select
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1)  tablename,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(statuss, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) status
 from
 numbers inner join (select 'Pricing,Billing,Compliance'  as 'tablename',concat(Pricing.status,',',Billing.status,',',Compliance.status )as 'statuss'
from Pricing,Billing,Compliance) as s on CHAR_LENGTH(s.tablename)
-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(s.tablename, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
```

Comment: This you can do in one single query or without using union

Answer (score 0):

create a VIEW by joining these tables. and call view any time (single query result). you have to create VIEW once and fire query on VIEW anytime.